# How to get zero values on query result grouped by month, if it doesn't contain any records

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've got IP address, email address and date in table. I need to find out how many mails was sent (grouped by IP and email together) during each month of each year (so group by month and year to). Tricky part is, that if no mail was sent, I need to get zero value on results (now I don't get empty rows). How can I do that?

```
Select distinct X.Sender, X.IP, MONTH(s.date) as Month, YEAR (s.date) as Year, Count(s.ID)
From
(
    Select TOP 10 a.Sender, a.SenderIP as IP, COUNT(a.ID) as C
    From AMA a Where a.Summary = 'SPAM' 
    Group by a.Sender, a.SenderIP 
    Order by C desc
)As X left outer join AMAs
on X.Sender = s.Sender and X.IP = s.SenderIP 
Where s.Summary = 'SPAM' 
Group by X.Sender, X.IP, YEAR(s.date), MONTH(s.date)
Order by X.Sender,X.IP,YEAR(s.date) asc, Month(s.date) asc`
```

Comment: SQL cannot generate data that is not present to begin with. If you need a 0 for a time span that is not in the data to begin with, you'll have to provide it via some other method. Most people generate a temp table listing the range of dates they want and join the real query against that.

Comment: There is not any kind of indicator. They have record only if they were successfully sent. So you said, the best solution is create temporary table filled with all months of all years and than join it to my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to `OUTER JOIN` from a set of months onto your existing resultset. This way, all months with data will be present, and any months without data will have empty values.

You could create a table with that information, or you could use a CTE.

```
DECLARE @firstDate DATE = '2010-01-01';

WITH Months (fulldate) AS
(
    SELECT @firstdate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, fulldate) 
    FROM Months 
    WHERE fulldate < GETDATE()
)
SELECT
    m.*, q.*
FROM Months m
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (  
        -- your existing query 
    ) q
    ON q.[Year] = DATEPART(YEAR, fulldate) 
    AND q.[Month] = DATEPART(MONTH, fulldate)
-- you may need to increase the max recursion, if you want more than 100 months...
-- OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

Comment: I am afraid that this did not do it, but thanks for your help anyway! I get the same results as before, except for the month when all of the emails have zero count - there I get a sigle row with date and NULLs. I need to get a row for every month for every email of the TOP 10 with count, even if the count is zero.

Comment: You want zeros instead of nulls? You should try searching SO or googling for that.

Comment: OK, I probably was not clear enough, sorry. [have a look at the query result.](http://images.megaupload.cz/UntitledvSOa2.jpg) See what I mean? For example I need <alpineprogram@... to have a row for august 2010 (and all other months from a certain time span) with count 0 (or null, does not really matter).

Comment: I see what you mean. I mostly focused on your titled and seems I didn't read the code thoroughly enough. However the pattern that I've presented here still stands: you need to create a set of *rows you want* and then outer join than onto the set of *row you have*. Instead of just joining on month/year, you'll also want to join on sender/IP. This is the pattern, I'll leave the implementation up to you.